# Passing string from one WinForm to another doesnt work

Tags: string, winforms

This is my C# ADO.NET app. I am trying to pass name of my logged user from my LoginForm to my MainMenuForm. Name must be visible on my label in MainMenuForm. After Login is succesfull I am closing my LoginForm and my MainMenuForm is displayed. I made property for that, but my label in MainMenuForm display nothing. Here is my code:

LoginForm code:

```
    Persons LoggedPerson = new Persons();
    public LoginForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        tbPassword.PasswordChar='*';
        tbPassword.MaxLength = 9;
    }




    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Boolean flag = false;
        string username= tbUsername.Text;
        string password = tbPassword.Text;
        var sadrzaj = new NFC_baseEntities1();
        foreach (var x in sadrzaj.Persons) {
            if (x.Username==username && x.Password==password) 
            {
                LoggedPerson.Name= x.Name;
                LoggedPerson.Surname= x.Surname;
                flag = true;
                break;

            }

        }

        if (flag == false)
        {
            DialogResult dialog = MessageBox.Show("Invalid username or password!", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
           if(dialog==DialogResult.OK)
                   Application.Exit();


        }
        else
        {
            DialogResult dialog = MessageBox.Show("Username and password are correct!", "Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
            if (dialog == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                MainMenu forma = new MainMenu();
                forma.Show();
                this.Hide();
            }
        }

    }

    public string TheName
    {
        get { return this.LoggedPerson.Name + " " + LoggedPerson.Surname; }


    }
```

MainMenuForm code:

```
public MainMenu()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        LoginForm nova = new LoginForm();
        MenuLbLoggedPerson.Text += nova.TheName;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that your `LoginForm` is your startup form, you are creating your `MainMenu` in your `LoginForm` then in your `MainMenu`'s constructor you are creating another `LoginForm` **it is a totally separate instance** and your login information is not available. Try adding a method to your `MainMenu` and set it from your `LoginForm` instead.

**MainMenu**

```
public MainMenu()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

public void SetLogin(string loginInfo)
{
    MenuLbLoggedPerson.Text = loginInfo;
}
```

**LoginForm**

```
MainMenu forma = new MainMenu();
forma.SetLogin(LoggedPerson.Name + " " + LoggedPerson.Surname);
forma.Show();
this.Hide();
```